# unable to send message to external web application using camel

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, fuseesb, cxfrs

My requirement is to recieve a message a json object from a webapplication and route it (Json object) to another web application ,I am using camel for this purpose,in what should be a fairly simple process is now giving me sleepless nights,My camel route is given as below

```
                 <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="cxfrs://bean://lmrServer" />
        <camel:to uri="log:output?showAll=true"/>
             <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
         <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader> 
    <camel:to uri="cxfrs:http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/message"/>
```

Now below is my error stack,where I can see the json object in the message body,can some please let me know where Iam wrong,it would be of great help..Thanks in advance..

```
[               qtp177816476-20] output                         INFO  Exchange[I
d:ID-UKCNU1161RK1-53103-1382261880815-0-1, ExchangePattern:InOut, Properties:{Ca
melToEndpoint=log://output?showAll=true, CamelCreatedTimestamp=Sun Oct 20 10:38:
32 BST 2013}, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-UKCNU1161RK1-53103-1382261880815-0-2, Cam
elHttpPath=/lmr/register, CamelAcceptContentType=*/*, CamelCxfRsOperationResourc
eInfoStack=[org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.MethodInvocationInfo@7bfd523d], CamelHttp
Uri=/jkdlrn/lmr/register, connection=keep-alive, content-type=application/json,
Host=localhost:8081, Content-Length=67, CamelCxfRsResponseGenericType=void, Came
lHttpCharacterEncoding=ISO-8859-1, CamelCxfMessage=org.apache.cxf.message.XMLMes
sage@c6298812, CamelHttpMethod=POST, User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.
5), CamelCxfRsResponseClass=void, operationName=register}, BodyType:org.apache.c
xf.message.MessageContentsList, Body:[MemberApplication [name=xyz, organization=
avc, nic=xyz, employeeId=5920]], Out: null]
[               qtp177816476-20] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed del
ivery for (MessageId: ID-UKCNU1161RK1-53103-1382261880815-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-
UKCNU1161RK1-53103-1382261880815-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caugh
t: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution
 on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [MemberApplication [name=xyz, organization=a
vc, nic=xyz, employeeId=5920]]]
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on
 the exchange: Exchange[Message: [MemberApplication [name=xyz, organization=avc,
 nic=xyz, employeeId=5920]]]
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(Object
Helper.java:1287)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.ja
va:282)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncP
rocessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64)[camel-core-2.10.3.
jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProc
essor.java:122)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.j
ava:298)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:1
17)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(Delegat
eAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsy
ncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(Instrume
ntationProcessor.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(Delegat
eAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsy
ncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(Trace
Interceptor.java:91)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler
(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryE
rrorHandler.java:220)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteCon
textProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsy
ncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(Default
Channel.java:303)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[camel-
core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-c
ore-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteCon
textProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsy
ncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWor
kProcessor.java:150)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProc
essor.java:117)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNe
xt(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsy
ncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(Delegat
eAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsy
ncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(Instrume
ntationProcessor.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.asyncInvoke(CxfRsIn
voker.java:87)[camel-cxf-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.performInvocation(C
xfRsInvoker.java:57)[camel-cxf-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker
.java:89)[cxf-rt-core-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:166)[cxf-r
t-frontend-jaxrs-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:93)[cxf-rt
-frontend-jaxrs-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInv
okerInterceptor.java:58)[cxf-rt-core-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)[:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1
.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_25]
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecu
tor.java:37)[cxf-rt-core-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(Se
rviceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)[cxf-rt-core-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseIntercept
orChain.java:263)[cxf-api-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainIniti
ationObserver.java:123)[cxf-rt-core-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceReque
st(JettyHTTPDestination.java:323)[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(Je
ttyHTTPDestination.java:289)[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTP
Handler.java:72)[cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
er.java:943)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
r.java:879)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:117)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont
extHandlerCollection.java:250)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
.java:110)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)[jetty-server-
7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.
java:441)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpCo
nnection.java:936)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)[jett
y-http-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
[jetty-http-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnecti
on.java:51)[jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEn
dPoint.java:586)[jetty-io-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEnd
Point.java:44)[jetty-io-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo
l.java:598)[jetty-util-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool
.java:533)[jetty-util-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_25]
[               qtp177816476-20] WebApplicationExceptionMapper  WARN  WebApplica
tionException has been caught : org/apache/cxf/service/factory/ReflectionService
FactoryBean
```

I have  a feeling that its because of the jars so below is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <camel.version>2.10.3</camel.version>
        <json.version>1.8.5</json.version>
        <cxf.version>2.5.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cache</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${json.version}</version>
</dependency>



        <!-- CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-addr</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- -jetty -->
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <connectors>
                <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                  <port>8081</port>
                </connector>
              </connectors>
              <stopPort>18080</stopPort>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ok, @Pith now I made the changes suggested by you, now its throwing the below error

```
el 2.10.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.498 seconds
[              qtp1431523121-14] output                         INFO  Exchange[E
xchangePattern:InOut, BodyType:org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList, Body:
[{"name":"xyz", "organization":"avc", "nic":"xyz", "employeeId":"5920"}]]
[              qtp1431523121-14] BusApplicationContext          INFO  Refreshing
 org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@1ccffe62: startup date [Tue Oct
 22 15:46:42 BST 2013]; parent: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXml
ApplicationContext@4642ebd
[              qtp1431523121-14] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed del
ivery for (MessageId: ID-UKCNU1161RK1-52360-1382453193775-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-
UKCNU1161RK1-52360-1382453193775-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caugh
t: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apach
e.cxf.message.MessageContentsList
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.c
xf.message.MessageContentsList
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.DefaultCxfRsBinding.bindCamelMes
sageBodyToRequestBody(DefaultCxfRsBinding.java:166)[camel-cxf-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]

        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.invokeHttpClient(C
xfRsProducer.java:143)[camel-cxf-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.process(CxfRsProdu
cer.java:87)[camel-cxf-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncP
rocessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.10.3.
jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProc
essor.java:122)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.j
ava:298)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:1
17)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelp
er.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(Delegat
```

changes I made in my camel -context is the below

```
<dataFormats>
        <json library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="org.payment.camel.example.MemberApplication" id="jack"/>
    </dataFormats>
```

MemberApplication is just a pojo class implementing Serializable..Can some one point me out where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exchange's body is containing an object

```
BodyType:org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList, Body:[MemberApplication [name=xyz, organization=avc, nic=xyz, employeeId=5920]]
```

shouldn't that be converted to json before being sent to

```
<camel:to uri="cxfrs:http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/message"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,my requirement is to send the same json object which I am receiving to the external web application,Is there any way I can perform that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send JSON, you have to marshall your object before.

You can do it like this:

```
<dataFormats>
    <!-- here we define a Json data format with the id jack and that it should use the TestPojo as the class type when
         doing unmarshal. The unmarshalTypeName is optional, if not provided Camel will use a Map as the type -->
    <json id="jack" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="org.apache.camel.component.jackson.TestPojo"/>
</dataFormats>

<camel:route>
     <camel:from uri="cxfrs://bean://lmrServer" />
        <camel:to uri="log:output?showAll=true"/>
             <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
         <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader> 
     <camel:marshal ref="jack"/>
     <camel:to uri="cxfrs:http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/message"/>
 </camel:route>
```

See the doc for more details: [camel-json doc](http://camel.apache.org/json).